# Get all parents of an element including the element itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an array of all the elements to where the user clicked in a content editable div. I have this working with the following code.

```
 var els = [];
 var target = event.target;
 while (target){ //Create an array of parent elements
    els.push(target); //Push target to the back of the array
    target = target.parentNode; 
}
```

But I was wondering if I could reduce this to one line with jQuery. jQuery `.parents()` almost gets me there but it doesn't include the first `event.target`

```
var els = $(event.target).parents();
```

Is there a way to include the element itself with `.parents()` or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can use `andSelf` to include the target element.

Comment: I have tried andSelf() and it returns the reverse of the array.

Comment: Have you assigned an `onclick` event to parent element ?

Comment: I have a click event for the content editable div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [andSelf](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) ?

```
var els = $(event.target).parents().andSelf();
```

Mine would get you, great-grandparent, grandparent, parent, self.

If you want: self, parent, grandparent, great-grandparent, try extending Jquery with this:

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
```

and then doing:

```
var els = `$(event.target).parents().andSelf().reverse();
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhBf9/5/)

Comment: This worked after combining with dystroy .get().reverse() Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) :

```
var els = $(event.target).parents().add(event.target);
```

or, if you want them in a different order :

```
var els = $(event.target).add($(event.target).parents());
```

---

If what you need is an array (ie not a jQuery object), you can use reverse :

```
var els = $(event.target).parents().add(event.target).get().reverse();
```

Comment: This seems to almost do it but both your methods come up with the reverse of what I want it seems.

Comment: I have chosen to go with Treborbob answer but +1 for the .get().reverse()